# how to set action backBarButtonItem in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationbar, backbarbuttonitem

How to to set action backBarButtonItem and still display left arrow?

I used this code but the arrow was not display

```
var barBack = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Reset", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "reset:")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBack
```

but when I used this code the action not working

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = barBack
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to setting an action, you can keep the `backBarButtonItem` and use `isMovingFromParentViewController` instead to handle logic for moving back on the navigation stack.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if isMovingFromParentViewController() {
        .. do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var barBack = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Reset", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "reset:")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBack
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: It seems like my code. Please read my question carefully. thanks

Comment: Actually it is kinda different because you are using the top item property of the navigation bar of the navigation controller which might not always be active such as when the page is not embedded in a navigation controller. I am, on the other hand, using the leftBarButtonItem of the page's navigationItem. Please try my code and see if it works because I tried it before posting the answer

Comment: The only thing common between our codes is the initialisation of the barbuttonitem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In `ViewDidLoad`

```
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< Home", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goBack")
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "the_font_you_want_to_use", size: size_of_the_font_this_should_be_integer)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

and implement the following method:

```
    func goBack() {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(boolean)
}
```

Just replace the the_font_you_want_to_use, size_of_the_font_this_should_be_integer and boolean with the values you want, and everything will be working.

*** EDIT

If you don't want to get back to `Root View Controller`, instead of

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(boolean)
```

you can say:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(boolean)
```

or even pop to some other `ViewController` with specifying the first parameter of the `popToViewController` to be the object of `YourViewController` class, and second the boolean value for animation.